# Stop Hacks to Wordpress Site - New User Added

Tags: wordpress, security, authorization

My apologies in advance if I am posting it in the wrong forum.

I have a WordPress site. Every couple of days, a new user is added as an "Administrator" as shown below

[image]

I have changed my password many times using complex passwords but to no use. I even searched on Google and have read links like [this one](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/someone-registered-as-a-user-on-my-wordpress-blog-possible-hacker).

I have also unchecked the option "**Anyone can register**"

[image]

However, I am unable to stop them from registering.

Fortunately, no malicious activity has been noticed (Ex: Deletions/Unwanted posts etc)

Please advise me on what I can do to stop these?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You clearly have a more serious compromise, like an uploaded malicious script or an unpatched vulnerability. You need to rebuild your site from scratch (clean install of the current versions of WP and any plugins and themes, using a known-good database export) ASAP before something really bad happens.

Unfortunately, it's impossible to say what happened without digging through your server. My guess is that somebody exploited a vulnerability and uploaded a script. It could be anything - an hole in the WP core, a plugin, or a theme; a malicious plugin or theme; a stolen password; a breach of another site on the same server; or a number of other things.

Regardless of what happened, the only safe fix is to rebuild the site. If you have data backups, you can achieve this in a few hours.

I strongly recommend installing the security plugin WordFence to help prevent similar problems in the future. (I have no affiliation with WordFence, but use it on a number of sites.)

Finally, you might want to read [this discussion on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server). The consensus in this situation is "nuke it from orbit." Good luck!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to shed more light into it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Unfortunately, it's impossible to say what happened without digging through your server. My guess is that somebody exploited a vulnerability and uploaded a script. It could be anything - an hole in the WP core, a plugin, or a theme; a malicious plugin or theme; a stolen password; a breach of another site on the same server; or a number of other things. Regardless, the only safe fix is to rebuild the site. If you have data backups, you can achieve this in a few hours. I strongly recommend installing WordFence (security plugin) to help prevent similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 7):

Someone is making a SQL injection in your site.
If you want to prevent this in future, you should do some things.

- Rebuild your website from scratch.
- Install some of the security plugins, like `Bulletproof Security, Wordfence, iThemes Security`. I suggest you to buy the license of Bulletproof, or use the free version + one of the others. And be careful for the equal settings.
- The most common attack are with SQL Injection XSS, Plugin exploits and of course brute-forcing the admin pass. You should upgrade every plugin and Wordpress every time when you see a new version.
- Use less plugins. They are one of the main reason for hacked websites. If you use Linux, Ican tell you how to scan your website for vulnerabilities. Or just tell me the url, and I will tell you the results.
- Also change your `/wp-admin path`, there are a lot of bots who search the web and make bruteforce attacks.

Also is important to use `different admin username` from `admin` or `Admin`. And use strong passwords. It's a good practice when you make a new Wordpress installation, to do two more users. The first will be an `Author` and will post everything in the site, the second you should make with `Administration role`. After that delete the first admin user and start the new one. 
Hackers knows that almost every time the user with `id:1` is the admin, so they can try to access again. So in this case your admin will be with id:3, and again don't use username like admin and etc.

Best regards and wish you luck.
Kasmetski

Comment: Here is the output. You have a lot of wholes. For a start, Install the latest Wordpress 4.2.2 and upgrade all plugins to the latest version.

Look here for detailed overview. I had paste the whole audit - http://pastebin.com/6Yf7YpGH

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I went to the dashboard and it says that the wordpress is already updated to 4.2.2 Just to be sure I did a re-install. It also tells me that all plugins are updated?

Comment: You should update and the theme to version 2.5. In your current version it has two vulnerabilities.
`[!] Title: DejaVu 2.4 - dl-skin.php _mysite_delete_skin_zip Parameter Absolute Path Traversal Remote Directory Deletion
    Reference: https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7450
    Reference: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/30443/
[i] Fixed in: 2.5

[!] Title: DejaVu 2.4 - dl-skin.php _mysite_download_skin Parameter Absolute Path Traversal Remote File Download
    Reference: https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/7451
    Reference: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/30443/
[i] Fixed in: 2.5
`

Comment: The things which I mentioned before will save you from lame hackers, and auto-hacking with bots for wordpress sites. If a good hacker wants access, he will get it,no matter what :)

Comment: Did you make a new wordpress and theme installation from scratch? Also change all passwords, for the ftp, for the database user, for the cpanel & etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check index.php, wp-admin/index.php to see if they have been modified. Usually the following line of code is added to the top of the index.php file. A code starting with 'required' is usually added.
   The file being ‘required’/’included’ here contains malicious code which is executed along with each run of WordPress. Such code can generate fake pharma pages, Japanese SEO spam pages and other malware infections.
   Delete the @require code from the file after comparing it with the contents of the core WP files from it’s GitHub repository.
2. Check if there are any new files in the root of the server or /wp-admin folder that were not created by you. Some of the files that you may find are:

   - Marvins.php
   - db_.php
   - 8c18ee
   - 83965
   - admin.php
   - buddy.zip
   - dm.php

If you find any of the above suspicious files, take a backup and delete them.

Source: https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/fix-wordpress-admin-dashboard-wp-admin-hack/